# How to change font size with the python-pptx library

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to change the font size of the bullet points I added to my PowerPoint presentation using Python.

```
for bullet_point in text:
       i += 0.5
       body_shape = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left=Inches(1), top=Inches(i), width=Inches(6),       height=Inches(1))
       tf = body_shape.text_frame
       tf.text = bullet_point
```

Why is this not working correctly?

Comment: Where did you change the font size?

Comment: As @PranavHosangadi said… where is the attempt to change font size? Python-pptx’s documents cover this here - https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html